# No feedback when a user adds a bounty whilst you're adding one

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, bounties

Ok, so queue an edge case (but no, it's not [Friday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland) yet).

If you are in the process of adding a bounty, but another user adds a bounty to the question *whilst* you are in the "Add Bounty" workflow, upon pressing the "Start Bounty" button, the page reloads... but you get no feedback as to what happened.

- Your bounty doesn't appear
- Nothing tells you someone beat you to it

**Ideally** we could spawn one of those fancy notices along the lines of;

[image]

Comment: A rather rare occurrence, I should think. And you would see the other bounty notice...

Comment: @Oded: I'd agree on it being a rare occurrence (edge case anyone? :))... and you can, but it's not what you immediately look for and I'm  *sure* a) It'd confuse some people, and b) would be easy to add the message.

Comment: Sorry my bad :D.

Comment: This is totally a feature request, surely not a bug.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's possible to get data on this, but I can't believe this happens more than once a month - and that seems generous.

- It's very quick to add a bounty.  It's not like writing an answer where you worry about spacing and code formatting and getting all your links right.  It's s 15 second operation AT MOST
- It's unlikely that two users will want to bounty the same question at the same time in the first place

So, to pay off, we need to have a high frequency of multiple users posting bounties in the same 15-second window on the same question.

And the big problem that we would avoid by adding a special trap for this extremely rare scenario is...minor inconvenience and possible confusion?  It should be pretty obvious what has happened if you do this, as you yourself mention in the comments.

You say "itd confuse some people" but we are talking about 1 additional confused person a month, which for SO is like a single hydrogen atom somewhere in the vastness of the sun.

Even if it only took 15 minutes of admin time to put this in place, it'll take 5 years (assuming 1 occurrence a month that costs someone 15 seconds) for it to pay off.  In 5 years we will all be answering questions with our minds anyways so it will be a moot point.

Comment: Agree. To make it short: it's not worth the development time. :)

Comment: I'm not doubting it's a rare occurance, but I disagree a bounty is added in 15 seconds. You sit and stare at the first screen and try highlighting the difference bounty levels until it gets too painful. You then choose the reason. You can then type out a reason (optional, but I did). I spent 3-5 minutes adding the bounty. We're not adding a trap, clearly the trap is already there otherwise we'd have had 2 bounties. All we need to do is output an error message as well! [It's not obvious if the bounty message is off the screen as was (and is often) the case](http://i.stack.imgur.com/D7gxr.jpg).

Comment: p.s. your math is flawed; it'll take 1.6(66666...) years to pay off the development time ;). With my estimate of 3-5 minutes however, it'll take 1-2 months.

Comment: @Matt - You're right I was using 15 mins of admin time but typed 5.  regardless it's not worth it.  Also if it takes you 5 minutes to post a bounty, then the issue is between the chair and the keyboard and not something we need to code around.

Comment: *"... between the chair and the keyboard and not something we need to code around.*, haha, love it ;).